# Software update on Azure IoT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-edge

I am currently working on software update on iot device using Microsoft azure.
I am following the below links for the same

```
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-firmware-update#update-the-firmware"
"https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-iot-workbench/blob/master/docs/iot-devkit/devkit-ota.md"
```

I am referring to this link. I have few doubt regarding this link. If you check the overall architecture diagram it says that there is IOT dev kit which contains IOT C SDK with OTA handler, OTA utility APIs, Firmware Update API for IOT gateway/deevice side. I am not able to find this IOT dev kit.

I am just starting with Azure, I do not have much idea about it. Where can I get IOT dev kit with all OTA functionality enabled. I am actually trying for software update and not firmware update. What approach should be taking for this?

Comment: "IoT Dev Kit" in the architecture diagram refers to this one: https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/ - it's the MxChip board for developing/learning Azure IoT.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I am currently using my Ubuntu laptop as IOT device connected to azure. Now I want to update any packages (i.e. python library, configuration file, etc) on Ubuntu using azure IOT hub. Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: This topic provides an overview regarding device management from Azure IoTHub. Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-management-overview

Answer (score 0):

The link you referring is a special OTA Update project for IoT Devkit (AZ3166).
You need to know that the IoT Devkit is running [MICO](http://en.mxchip.com/product/mico) which stands for Micro-Controller based Internet Connectivity Operating System.

So this is currently the main difference between the MXChip and your Laptop as IoT Device which is running Ubuntu as operating system. The DevKit-SDK is synchronizing a given Image-URL with the new firmware of MXChip and downloading it. After this the [OTAFirmwareUpdate.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/devkit-sdk/blob/master/AZ3166/src/cores/arduino/system/OTAFirmwareUpdate.cpp) is flashing the downloaded image on line 19.

So this is a basically difference when you want to run commands for updating your Linux packages. For the scenario you mentioned it could be helpful to receive the update commands via desired properties and therefore create programmatically a bash script and execute it?